# What is the command in Unix something like .a/.exe to run a file you just compiled?

Tags: unix, terminal

I'd been using it for a while but just forgot. It would be after gcc filename.c

Comment: I got it to work with .a/.exe

Answer (score 3):

Normally you specify the name of the executable with the `-o` option to the compiler or linker, and then you run the program with that name. If you didn't use this option the default executable name is `a.out`.